# AVFoundation zoom help needed

Tags: iphone, ios, avfoundation

I have been reading the AVFoundation docs and I have just not been able to find any sort of API for the zoom functionality of the camera.

Could anyone give my any pointers about where to look for information?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no hardware zoom on any of current (and previous) versions of the iPhone/iPad/iPod. You can achieve software zoom a couple a different way. Probably the easiest would be to use a view's layer's transform property and set it to something like CGAffineTransformMakeScale(2.0f, 2.0f). You can then clip to an appropriate region.